# Doc-type Commented out in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: html, internet-explorer, doctype

I've noticed some weird behavior with a CMS i'm using. The Doctype is commented out in Internet Explorer 7 (IE9 in IE7 standards mode) see attached image:

[image]

I think this is causing a few other errors i have with CSS and JavaScript (jQuery).

Does anyone know anything that will trigger this behavior.

The doctype i'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the DOCTYPE has determined whether to use quirks (like IE5.5) mode or slightly-more-standards (IE7 native) mode, the DOCTYPE is not really of interest to the browser any further.

It seems that IE7 (at least) then inserts the doctype into the DOM as if it was a comment.

It's just the way the browser works. Unless you've JavaScript walking the DOM, it's unlikely to affect the way the page works.

Comment: When you mean javascript walking the dom, you mean using jQuery as a selector to do stuff. How could i get around that.

Comment: @etoxin - not really. I just mean that there's an exceptional case where you could have javascript code that assumed that the children of the document node were a document type node, optionally white space, and the `html` element, since that's what it ought to contain. If it in fact didn't because the document type node was replaced by a comment node, then the javascript might break. But it's just a theoretical possiblity, not a likelihood. Don't worry about it.

Comment: This is a terrible reply above me. The asker is specifically wanting information on WHY it happens and HOW to fix it, and when people are looking on search engines (i.e. me) to find an answer to similar issues, THIS is what we get.
This above phenomenon is happening to my website as well, and it is causing some CSS to become nonapplicable, which severely reduces the aesthetics of the website. To post "not worry about it cuz it's unlikely going to do anything" as a valid answer is ridiculous.
People should not respond unless they can answer the question.

Comment: @jk0 The answer explains why it happens. As per how to avoid it, I think the answer means there aren't ways to avoid it happens, and it should not have any relevance if it happens, since normally the document type is not an information relevant.